# .htaccess start page with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directoryindex

When I open https://my-web-site.com/ ( my start page ) I would like to execute https://my-web-site.com/index.html rather https://my-web-site.com/app.php rewrite by apache.

I want to keep my rewrite rules and just bypass index.html.

My file index.html is correctly host and return to me the good file result :  https://my-web-site.com/index.html

I don't understand why if I tried to change DirectoryIndex https://my-web-site.com/ still call app.php (my default php route) :

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Is it beacause of rewrite rules ? Or maybe my host ignore DirectoryIndex ?
My web site is host by OVH on https://www.ovh.com/fr/hebergement-web/hebergement-performance.xml.

Here is my .htaccess (original version .htaccess of symfony )

Thank you in advance for your help

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.html

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the following  Redirect you have in your htaccess

`RedirectMatch 302 ^ /$ / app.php/` this is redirecting the homepage of your site to `/app.php` .  Simply remove this and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRules are applied before DirectoryIndex, so it will never be applied since `/` will already be rewritten to `/app.php`.

If you need this only for root folder, you can instead of `DirectoryIndex index.html` try:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
# this will immediately rewrite / to /index.html
```

or you can add this after your `DirectoryIndex index.html`:

```
RewriteRule ^$ - [END]
# this will prevent execution of any other RewriteRules, 
# so DirectoryIndex will be applied
```